# How do you re-evaluate the value of a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables

Is there a way to re evaluate the value of a variable that is dependent on other variables in Python? Let me provide a simple example.

```
a = 1
b = a + 1
a = 5
re-evaluate(b) # ???
```

Is there a way to re-evaluate the value of the variable b now that a has changed, so that it returns 6?

Comment: this is something of a math-view gotcha; `=` is for assignment, not equality!

Comment: No, this is fundamentally not how variables work. You assign the *result* of expressions, some object, to a variable. That object has no idea what expression created it. Instead, you probably just want to use a *function*.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function:

```
a = 1
def func(a):
    b = a + 1
    return b
b = func(a)
print(b)
a = 5
b = func(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
2
6
```

As you can see it reevaluated.